# How to get image hight after the image has fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some images that are not small and I need to use jQuery to get their height and width after they have loaded in the respective div. 
This question has been asked before and I tried many of the suggestions.
For example: The following code was suggested and it only works intermittently on each page refresh:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".youtube-image-thumbnail img").on('load', function() {
    console.log(jQuery(this).height());
  });

});
```

This solution did not work at all

```
jQuery(function() {
  console.log('here')
  jQuery(".youtube-image-thumbnail img").bind('load', function() {
    console.log(jQuery(this).height());
  });
});
```

My html element looks like this:

```
<div class="youtube-image-thumbnail">
<img src="/youtube_image/public/video_thumbnails/exvLChu1-fk.jpg?itok=q0nFDq8g" alt="" typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

Here is a [JsFiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/oxdqe42L/2/) 
Am I missing anything or is there a better more sound solution?

Comment: Are the `youtube-image-thumbnail` element and its child image loaded asynchronously or do they exist in the DOM upon document ready?

Comment: Normal element not loaded asynchronously. I'll update the question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

At the time you've binded the `img`, it's already loaded.

This approach would work if you bind it first.

On (this example)[https://jsfiddle.net/oxdqe42L/4/] I've changed the `img` source after the bind, then the loading event has trigged the binded handler

Comment: Thanks your solution gave me couple of ideas, but locally and on a server it is still intermittent. Perhaps there is something else interfering. I could use the timeout to trigger the JS multiple times. Or look for a native JS solution.